# How do I get logs from all pods of a Kubernetes replication controller?

Tags: logging, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Running `kubectl logs` shows me the stderr/stdout of one Kubernetes container.

How can I get the aggregated stderr/stdout of a set of pods, preferably those created by a certain replication controller?

Comment: have in mind that not setting the tail argument when using a selector will default every pod log to 10 lines length

Answer (score 440, accepted):

You can use labels

```
kubectl logs -l app=elasticsearch
```

And you'd probably want to specify `--all-containers --ignore-errors` in order to:

- Include logs from pods with multiple containers
- Continue to next pod on fatal error (e.g. logs could not be retrieved)

Comment: Good solution and most likely enough to answer the original question but it won't tail: "error: only one of follow (-f) or selector (-l) is allowed".

Comment: Also, no `--all-namespaces`.

Comment: What will be the order of those logs? I mean if there are multiple pods and each pod will have their own logs. So if logs from all are displayed, then in what order will they be displayed and how do I identify a source pod of a particular log line?

Comment: It seems like this works with `-f` now (as of Kubernetes 1.12+ / `kubectl` 1.12+). Also @Shubham - it displays the messages in the order received, there are no tags or anything on the log lines. This is just for quick debugging. If you need more log detail, you'll need to ship your logs to a central logging system like EFK, SumoLogic, Datadog, etc.

Comment: Is there anyway to do the same using kubernetes dashboard.

Comment: You may also need `--all-containers` if there are multi-container pods. And `--max-log-requests=42` if there are many pods.

Comment: is there any way to do the same using the k8s client?

Comment: might want to use `-n <namespace> --tail=<lines>`

Comment: How do I get the label from `kubectl`?

Comment: Probably also want to pass `--prefix` to differentiate where the lines are from.

Comment: sometimes the number of containers under a pod can exceed maximum concurrent streams number. can further append `--max-log-requests {number of stream}` to combine all containers' logs in one stream

Comment: issue: stacktrace from multiple pods mixed together. how to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 100):

I've created a small bash script called `kubetail` that makes this possible. For example to tail all logs for pods named "app1" you can do:

```
kubetail app1
```

You can find the script [here](https://github.com/johanhaleby/kubetail).

Comment: Installed it with:  

`brew tap johanhaleby/kubetail && brew install kubetail --with-short-names`
detailed documentation: `kt -h`
Awesome!

Comment: Awesome. I have a couple of questions.
```
 1. Can we tail logs of multiple pods belonging to different deployments?
Something like "kt -l app=service1,app=service2"
 2. How do I write em all to a file? Doing this "kt -l app=service1` >> filename.log" writes only pod names to it.
 3. Does it also tail in case of autoscaling deployments?
```

Answer (score 56):

You can get the logs from multiple containers using labels as Adrian Ng suggested:

```
kubectl logs --selector app=yourappname
```

BUT in case you have a pod with multiple containers, the above command is going to fail and you'll need to specify the container name:

```
kubectl logs --selector app=yourappname --container yourcontainername
```

Note: If you want to see which labels are available to you, the following command will list them all:

```
kubectl get pod <one of your pods> -o template --template='{{.metadata.labels}}'
```

...where the output will look something like

> map[app:yourappname controller-revision-hash:598302898 pod-template-generation:1]

Note that some of the labels may not be shared by other pods - picking "app" seems like the easiest one

Answer (score 39):

To build on the previous answer if you add `-f` you can tail the logs.

```
kubectl logs -f deployment/app
```

Comment: Be careful! This command chooses only one pod to stream the logs. It doesn't stream the logs from all pods in the replica set/deployment.

Comment: best answer: kubectl logs -f --all-containers deployment/app

Comment: But it will still not log from all *pods* that run this deployment, only all *containers* within these pods (and usually you only have one container per pod, but multiple pods per deployment)

Answer (score 36):

Previously provided solutions are not that optimal. The kubernetes team itself has provided a solution a while ago, called stern.

```
stern app1
```

It is also matching regular expressions and does tail and -f (follow) by default. A nice benefit is, that it shows you the pod which generated the log as well.

```
app1-12381266dad-3233c foobar log
app1-99348234asd-959cc foobar log2
```

Grab the go-binary for linux or install via brew for OSX.

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/10/tail-kubernetes-with-stern/

https://github.com/stern/stern

Comment: I took a binary from https://github.com/wercker/stern/releases and it worked perfectly out of the box.  Thanks!

Comment: Now use the "friendly fork": https://github.com/stern/stern I got a not found for https://github.com/wercker/stern

Answer (score 22):

In this example, you can replace the `<namespace>` and `<app-name>` to get the logs when there are multiple Containers defined in a Pod.

```
kubectl -n <namespace> logs -f deployment/<app-name> \
    --all-containers=true --since=10m
```

Comment: this would be fantastic if it dumped days worth of logs, i wonder what the limits are?

Comment: for some reason, this command extracts logs for a random pod but not for all of them. I've switch to using labels instead

Answer (score 14):

You can get help from `kubectl logs -h` and according the info,

```
kubectl logs -f deployment/myapp -c myapp --tail 100
```

`-c` is the container name and `--tail` will show the latest num lines，but this will choose one pod of the deployment, not all pods. This is something you have to bear in mind.

```
kubectl logs -l app=myapp -c myapp --tail 100
```

If you want to show logs of all pods, you can use `-l` and specify a lable, but at the same time `-f` won't be used.

Comment: "but this will choose one pod of the deployment, not all pods" -> true and I've spent a lot of time debugging my app before realizing that not all logs were being displayed. This should be more explicit both in the other answers and the official docs.

Answer (score 13):

I use this simple script to get a log from the pods of a deployment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DEPLOYMENT=$1

for p in $(kubectl get pods | grep ^${DEPLOYMENT}- | cut -f 1 -d ' '); do 
    echo --------------------------- 
    echo $p 
    echo --------------------------- 
    kubectl logs $p
done
```

[Gist of the script](https://gist.github.com/Martlark/d9093394cc430195fc04b5fe7973e8c2)

Usage: log_deployment.sh "deployment-name".

Script will then show log of all pods that start with that "deployment-name".

Comment: You may output the pod name without using "cut" by using "kubectl get pods -o name."

Answer (score 11):

This answer attempts to provide a concise example along with an explanation. In order to get all the outputs of all the containers in a set of pods, you have to use labels (selectors) unless you plan on doing some additional scripting.

```
kubectl logs \
--namespace my-namespace \
-l app=my-app-label \
--tail=-1 \
--timestamps=true \
--prefix=true \
--all-containers=true
```

This example returns complete snapshot logs from all containers in pods defined by label `app=my-app-label`.

### Optional Options

It may be helpful to add the `--timestamps=true` and `--prefix=true` flags so that the timestamp and log source are visible in the output, but they are not required.

### Logs by Resource

If a resource such as a deployment is specified and that deployment has
multiple pods such as a ReplicaSet, then only one of the pods logs will be returned. This is why a selector is used to identify the pods.

Despite specifying `--all-containers`, targeting a resource such as a service or a deployment does not successfully return the logs of all containers in all pods using `kubectl` v1.22.5 when this response was written. This is why selectors must be used.

### Container Names

Per the output of `kubectl logs --help`

> Print the logs for a container in a pod or specified resource.
> If the pod has only one container, the container name is optional.

What this means is that if there is more than one container, you have to do one of the following:

- Let the command pick a container for you
- Use the `--all-containers=true` option

### Following and Tailing

If you specify a label as the example above does, then `tail` will get set to 10, returning only the last 10 logs for each container. To get all logs, set `tail` to `-1`.

Add `-f` or `--follow` to the example to follow the logs. If you don't need all of the logs, change the value of the `--tail` option. When tailing the logs, you may want to ensure that the default option `--max-log-requests=5` is sufficient. If there are 20 containers upping `--max-log-requests=20` is required.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, thank you for providing it. Using Helm's tags I was able to retreive the logs of all the APPNAME pods in my deployment using `kubectl logs -l app.kubernetes.io/name=APPNAME --all-containers=true --timestamps=true --prefix=true --tail=-1 --follow`. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

One option is to set up cluster logging via Fluentd/ElasticSearch as described at https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/logging/elasticsearch/. Once logs are in ES, it's easy to apply filters in Kibana to view logs from certain containers.

Answer (score 6):

You can do either of the following options based on your requirements:

1. `kubectl -n my_namespace logs deployment/my_deployment --all-containers=true --since 10m`
2. `for i in $(kubectl get pods -n "my_namespace" | sed 1d | cut -d" " -f1); do kubectl logs  $i -n "my_namespace" "app_name" | grep -i "filter_string you want to" ; done`

Answer (score 3):

If the pods are named meaningfully one could use simple Plain Old Bash:

```
keyword=nodejs
command="cat <("
for line in $(kubectl get pods | \
  grep $keyword | grep Running | awk '{print $1}'); do 
    command="$command (kubectl logs --tail=2 -f $line &) && "
  done
command="$command echo)"
eval $command
```

Explanation: Loop through running pods with name containing "nodejs". Tail the log for each of them in parallel (single ampersand runs in background) ensuring that if any of the pods fail the whole command exits (double ampersand). Cat the streams from each of the tail commands into a unique stream. Eval is needed to run this dynamically built command.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this by service name.

First, try to find the service name of the respective pod which corresponds to multiple pods of the same service. `kubectl get svc`.

Next, run the following command to display logs from each container.

```
kubectl logs -f service/<service-name>
```

Comment: 【Found 12 pods, using pod/xxx-app-234234-fdsfsd】， This is my output when using this command, it seems it didn't follow all 12 pods.

Answer (score 3):

@johan's answer gave me an idea of a one liner:

```
for i in $(kubectl get pods -n default |cut -d" " -f1); do kubectl logs $i -n default; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me:

> kubectl logs -n namespace -l app=label -c container

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that I would consider is using [K9S](https://github.com/derailed/k9s) which is a great kube administration tool.

After installation, the usage is very straightforward:

```
 k9s -n my-namespace --context the_context_name_in_kubeconfig
```

(If kubeconfig is not in the default location add `KUBECONFIG=path/to/kubeconfig` prefix).

The default view will list all pods as a list:

[image]

We can change the view to other Kube controllers like replica set (question asked for replication controllers so notice they are deprecated), deployments, cron jobs, etc' by entering a colon `:` and start typing the desired controller - as we can see K9S provides autocompletion for us:

[image]

And we can see all replica sets in the current namespace:

[image]

We can just choose the desired replica set by clicking enter and then we'll see the list of all pods which are related to this replica set - we can then **press on 'l' to view logs** of each pod.

So, unlike in the case of [stern](https://github.com/wercker/stern), we still need to go on each pod and view its logs but I think it is very convenient with K9S - we first view all pods of a related controller and then investigate logs of each pod by simply navigating with `enter`, `l` and `escape`.

Answer (score 0):

We've just launched a Kubernetes native logging tool that can collect logs from all the pods (that you specify) and send the logs to a centralised location.

I hope it helps anyone landing on this page: https://github.com/parseablehq/collector

Answer (score 0):

Pods are usually associated with "parent" resources like Services, Deployments and ReplicaSets, via some selector in those resources. In order to get the logs of all pods associated with a certain resource, you need to transform their selector into a valid `--selector` expression for `kubectl logs`.

For example, the following will generate a `--selector` expression for a Service:

```bash
kubectl --context "${CONTEXT}" --namespace "${NAMESPACE}" \
    get "service/${SERVICE}" --output=jsonpath='{.spec.selector}' \
| jq 'to_entries | map("\(.key)=\(.value)") | join(",")' -r
```

Thus, the following command would follow the logs of all Pods associated with the `${SERVICE}`:

```bash
kubectl --context "${CONTEXT}" --namespace "${NAMESPACE}" \
    logs --follow --all-containers --prefix --timestamps --selector "$(
        kubectl --context "${CONTEXT}" --namespace "${NAMESPACE}" \
            get "service/${SERVICE}" --output=jsonpath='{.spec.selector}' \
        | jq 'to_entries | map("\(.key)=\(.value)") | join(",")' -r
    )"
```

A similar thing can be expressed with `xargs`, if you don't like nesting:

```bash
kubectl --context "${CONTEXT}" --namespace "${NAMESPACE}" \
    get "service/${SERVICE}" --output=jsonpath='{.spec.selector}' \
| jq 'to_entries | map("\(.key)=\(.value)") | join(",")' -r \
| xargs -rn1 kubectl --context "${CONTEXT}" --namespace "${NAMESPACE}" \
    logs --follow --all-containers --prefix --timestamps --selector
```

Answer (score 0):

To tail all the logs across multiple replicas of the same pod, you can run `kubectl tail` in parallel like this. Set the level of parallelism to the number of the maximum number of replicas you want to follow.

```
kubectl -n ${NAMESPACE} \
  get pods --no-headers --output=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name \
  | xargs -n 1 -P 10 -I {} kubectl logs -f {}
```

How this works in brief:

- grab a list of all the pod names in `${NAMESPACE}`
- use `xargs` to launch a single (`-n 1`) copy of the command replacing `{}` with the line read from stdin (= pod name)

If you want to tail all the containers in the pod, you can still add `--all-containers` to the `logs` subcommand. In this case, I want no more than 10 pods to be tailed in parallel.

Answer (score -4):

I use this command.

```
kubectl -n <namespace> logs -f deployment/<app-name> --all-containers=true --since=10m
```

Comment: Hello! While that command may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: How is this answer different from @Gokul Gunasekaran's answer?

Answer (score -9):

Not sure if this is a new thing, but with deployments it is possible to do it like this:

```
kubectl logs deployment/app1
```

Comment: When you get logs by deployment it chooses any one the replicated pods (chooses randomly) but not all of them.

Comment: Downvoting because this only selects one pod