# kubernetes logging / get multiple source write to the main log entrypoint

Tags: logging, kubernetes

Not sure how to name it, but having a rails app, and using sidekiq; I'd like to be able to view both sidekiq and rails logs when running `kubectl logs {podname}`

Is that even possible ? is there another possibility (like extra commands to logs specific sources) ? Just wondering where to start investigating

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get logs from all pods of a Kubernetes replication controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069736/how-do-i-get-logs-from-all-pods-of-a-kubernetes-replication-controller)

Comment: Not really, I'm asking about what can internally be done in a controller to concat logs (think foreman, without foreman)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run your rails app in one container and sidekiq in another container. Both of them can run in the same pod. Assuming they're are indeed in the same pod but different containers then you can get each of their logs with the appropriate:

```
kubectl logs my-pod -c my-container
```

If otherwise you run them each in their own pods, getting each of their logs should be the default setup of just calling `kubectl logs my-pod` for each of them.

If you want to aggregate logs from multiple sources you should use something like [kubetail](https://github.com/johanhaleby/kubetail).

Comment: Ok makes sense. Still, you're confirming theres no way to 'concat' container logs ?

Comment: @Ben I didn't realize that's what you were after. I edited my answer and added a reference to kubetail which does what you mentioned.

Comment: Just use foreman...