# What are "snapshot logs" and how they differ from "standard(?) logs" in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I was looking for a way to stream the logs of all pods of a specific deployment of mine.
So, some days ago I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56258727/12603421) SO answer giving me a magical command:

```
kubectl logs -f deployment/<my-deployment> --all-containers=true
```

However, I've just discovered, after a lot of time debugging, that this command actually shows the logs of just one pod, and not all of the deployment.
So I went to [Kubectl's official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs) and found nothing relevant on the topic, just the following phrase above the example that uses the deployment, as a kind of selector, for log streaming:

```
  ...
  
  # Show logs from a kubelet with an expired serving certificate
  kubectl logs --insecure-skip-tls-verify-backend nginx
  
  # Return snapshot logs from first container of a job named hello
  kubectl logs job/hello
  
  # Return snapshot logs from container nginx-1 of a deployment named nginx
  kubectl logs deployment/nginx -c nginx-1
```

So why is that the first example shown says "Show logs" and the other two say "Return snapshot logs"?

Is it because of this "snapshot" that I can't retrieve logs from all the pods of the deployment?
I've searched a lot for more deep documentation on streaming logs with kubectl but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2):

To return all pod(s) log of a deployment you can use the same selector as the deployment. You can retrieve the deployment selector like this `kubectl get deployment <name> -o jsonpath='{.spec.selector}' --namespace <name>`, then you retrieve logs using the same selector `kubectl logs --selector <key1=value1,key2=value2> --namespace <name>`

Comment: Although your answer is useful, it doesn't answer my original question. But thank you!

Comment: `Is it because of this "snapshot" that I can't retrieve logs from all the pods of the deployment?` - no, as the answer demonstrates to you how you can you do that.