# can bash use kubectl get pods run a log watch sequentially?

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Note: this is more a bash/shell script issue than Kubernetes.

So I have one replica of a pod, and so `kubectl get pods` will only return one active replica.

Conceptually what I want to do is simple.  I want to do a `kubectl logs my-pod-nnn1` with a watcher, HOWEVER when that pod terminates I want to stream a message "my-pod-nnn1 terminated, now logging my-pod-nnn2", and then stream the new logs.  This is a fairly complex process (for me) and I'm wondering what approach I could take, and if this is possible (or perhaps not necessary) with multi-threading of some kind (which I have not done). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a rough outline for what you'll need to do, if I've read your needs right

```sh
slm-log-continue() {
  while true ; do
    PODLINE=$(kubectl get pod | grep regional-wkspce | grep Running | awk '/^regional-wkspce-.*/{print $1}')
    if [[ -z "$PODLINE" ]]; then
        echo no pod currently active, waiting 5 seconds ...
        sleep 5
    else
        echo "----- logging for $PODLINE -----"
        kubectl logs -f $PODLINE
        echo "----- pod $PODLINE disconnected -----"
    fi
  done
}
```

assuming kubectl logs terminates after the pod does and it's received the end of the logs ( I've not tested ), something like that should do what you need without any fancy multithreading. it will just find the current pod using whatever regex against the `get pods` output, extract the name and then spit out logs until it dies.

Comment: I have tested this and it works.  Thanks.  Of course it would only work for a case where there is only one Running replica present.  Any ideas on how to stream multiple logs at a time?  Obviously each line would need to be somehow parsed or intercepted and tagged with some initial string for source, or it would be confusing which pod they came from.

Comment: @OliverWilliams your edit removed the actual 5 second wait. hope you remembered it locally :P

Comment: @OliverWilliams  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069736/how-do-i-get-logs-from-all-pods-of-a-kubernetes-replication-controller it looks like you can use selectors to stream logs from multiple pods. good luck