# Does `kubectl log deployment/name` get all pods or just one pod?

Tags: kubernetes, logging, kubectl, distributed-computing

- I need to see the logs of all the pods in a deployment with N worker pods
- When I do `kubectl logs deployment/name --tail=0 --follow` the command syntax makes me assume that it will tail all pods in the deployment
- However when I go to process I don't see any output as expected until I manually view the logs for all N pods in the deployment

#### Does `kubectl log deployment/name` get all pods or just one pod?

Answer (score 1):

#### only one pod seems to be the answer.

- i went here [How do I get logs from all pods of a Kubernetes replication controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069736/how-do-i-get-logs-from-all-pods-of-a-kubernetes-replication-controller#comment124606499_56258727) and it seems that the command `kubectl logs deployment/name` only shows one pod of N
- also when you do execute the `kubectl logs` on a deployment it does say it only print to console that it is for one pod (not all the pods)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you run `kubectl logs` with a deployment, it will return the logs of only one pod from the deployment.

However, you can accomplish what you are trying to achieve by using the `-l` flag to return the logs of all pods matching a label.

For example, let's say you create a deployment using:

```
kubectl create deployment my-dep --image=nginx --replicas=3
```

Each of the pods gets a label `app=my-dep`, as seen here:

```
$ kubectl get pods -l app=my-dep
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
my-dep-6d4ddbf4f7-8jnsw   1/1     Running   0          6m36s
my-dep-6d4ddbf4f7-9jd7g   1/1     Running   0          6m36s
my-dep-6d4ddbf4f7-pqx2w   1/1     Running   0          6m36s
```

So, if you want to get the combined logs of all pods in this deployment you can use this command:

```
kubectl logs -l app=my-dep
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly run below command in order to get logs for all pods in kubernets by single command at once.

```
kubectl get pods -n default|grep -v NAME|awk '{print $1}'|while read pods;do kubectl logs $pods;echo;done
```