# How to Export NGINX Ingress Controller Logs

Tags: kubernetes, logging, nginx-ingress

I need to analyze the traffic to my K8s cluster (Not a Managed Cluster), so I need to export the logs.

NGINX logs are easy to export but NGINX Ingress Controller is new to me.

I am trying to find a solution on how to do this, but couldn't find it in the NGINX documentation.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the logs of the `nginx ingress controller` pod by simply using the command:

```
kubectl logs <nginx-ingress-controller-pod> -n <namespace>
```

If you want to export it, you just redirect the output of `kubectl logs` to a file:

```
kubectl logs <nginx-ingress-controller-pod> -n <namespace> > nginx-ingress-controller-pod.log
```

Would this solve your problem?

Comment: Mostly the ingress nginx controller is running in more than one replica. So it might be helpful to get the logs from the all pods https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069736/how-do-i-get-logs-from-all-pods-of-a-kubernetes-replication-controller

Comment: Not in the setup we have. But yeah, the `--all-containers` flag is an option in that case.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this. It worked. Thanks!